# Maven local dependency not resolving sub-dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm having problems resolving sub-dependencies from a third-party package. I'm a bit of a Maven beginner. Basically it goes like this:

```
git clone git://github.com/unidata/thredds.git
cd thredds
mvn install
```

Everything works great and stuff is installed into `~/.m2`. Now, I wrote my own code that uses the package that I just installed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>Test Package</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.ucar</groupId>
            <artifactId>netcdf</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Ok, this also works great when I run `mvn package`. The `netcdf` artifact is found. Now, when I try to run my code, I start down a long `ClassNotFoundException` path, having to keep adding all of `netcdf`'s dependencies to my classpath.

Am I doing something wrong, or should the `thredds` package and all its dependencies automatically be picked up?

**edit:** the thredds package has many sub-modules one of which is netcdf. My code only depends on the netcdf jar.

**edit:** the snapshot version is installed

```
$ ls -l ~/.m2/repository/edu/ucar/netcdf/4.3.8-SNAPSHOT/
total 4272
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nwatkins nwatkins     700 2012-03-29 23:23 maven-metadata-local.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nwatkins nwatkins     182 2012-03-29 23:23 _maven.repositories
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nwatkins nwatkins 4357494 2012-03-29 23:23 netcdf-4.3.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nwatkins nwatkins    7840 2012-03-29 22:28 netcdf-4.3.8-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

**edit:** to run the code which is in a single file `Test.java`

```
$ java -cp target/test-0.1.jar Test
```

**edit:** first error message

$ java -cp target/test-0.1.jar Test

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ucar/ma2/InvalidRangeException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ucar.ma2.InvalidRangeException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
```

**edit:** then I just try to manually add the dependency jar to the class path

```
$ java -cp ../thredds/cdm/target/netcdf-4.3.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:target/test-0.1.jar Test

xception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at ucar.nc2.NetcdfFile.<clinit>(NetcdfFile.java:97)
    at Test.main(Test.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 2 more
```

The `slf4j` package is also in `~/.m2`. I stopped trying to add things to the classpath after this as it seemed like the wrong approach. 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)

Comment: Where is a reference to thredds as dependency ? I only see netcdf as a dependency ?

Comment: Ahh, sorry. The thredds package has many sub-modules that are built and installed, one of which is netcdf. My program only depends on the netcdf package.

Comment: If the netcdf package really a SNAPSHOT if yes do you have the correct version ? Furthermore how do you run your code ?

Comment: I added edits at the bottom of the post to address your last 2 questions.

Comment: Hm. Can you post the whole error message in particular the ClassNotFoundException part...may be are searching in the wrong direction.

Comment: Added the error messages as edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions here (the cause of the problem has been explained in several answers):

1.Use maven exec plugin to launch your app:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <classpathScope>runtime</classpathScope>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <commandlineArgs>-classpath %classpath Test</commandlineArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

2.You can also package your jar with all its dependencies, using maven assembly plugin. To do that, you need to add the following to your plugins of your build:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>build-package</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then you can use the output jar created by maven assembly in your classpath arg

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to run your project from the target folder, and it is not seeing the transitive dependencies. You will need to use the maven dependencies plugin to have those dependencies copied over along with your jar file.

See also:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html

You can then define the dependencies on these jars either manually, or via a generated manifest file:
http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The maven project that you've created only packages your classes into test-0.1.jar.

If you use a simple `java` command to run your application, you MUST provide all other jars that your project depends on to the `-classpath` ( or `-cp` ) switch ( or through CLASSPATH environment variable ).

There are alternative packaging configurations that can copy all required dependencies into a single jar, if that is what you want.

Here is the example, which is a verbatim copy from here -> http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies-sect-basics.html.  I recommend that you read that whole chapter ( heck the whole book ) for better understanding.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.assemblies</groupId>
    <artifactId>executable-jar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Assemblies Executable Jar Example</name>
    <url>http://sonatype.com/book</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2-beta-2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-executable-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>
                                    jar-with-dependencies
                                </descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>org.sonatype.mavenbook.App</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I edited my post. I added the netcdf jar, but then there were transitive dependencies. I'd like those to automatically be resolved.

Comment: @Noah.  If you use `create-executable-jar` assembly, all transitive dependencies will be added to resulting jar.

Comment: @khmarbaise. As I said in my post, this is a verbatim copy from the book.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all the dependencies in classpath, when running your jar, you can use the maven-exec-plugin to run the program from withing maven, and have all the dependencies automatically added to your classpath.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the dependency for:

org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

which means in other words you need to add a dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Assuming you are using log4j ?

And furthermore based on the missing class: ucar.ma2.InvalidRangeException it looks you need an other supplemental dependency except (May be take a look into the documentation if exists).

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.ucar</groupId>
        <artifactId>netcdf</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```